# Second call to AVAudioPlayer -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code posted, what did I miss?)

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I'm using this code to play a different mp3 files with every call. The first time through works great. The second time crash, as indicated below.

.h

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

.m

```
-(void)load:(NSURL *)aFileURL {
 if (aFileURL) {

  AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: aFileURL
                      error: nil];

  [aFileURL release];
  self.player = newPlayer; // CRASHES HERE EXC_BAD_ACCESS with second MP3a
  [newPlayer release];

  [self.player prepareToPlay];
  [self.player setDelegate:self];
 }   
}
```

I know I must have missed something, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [aFileURL release];
```

You should not `-release` the url in `-load:`, since that function is not an owner. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is probably due to double-release of that URL.

Try to remove this line.

Comment: That's how you know you've been staring at the screen too long!!! Totally forgot about that. Jordan time-to-take-a-break, Much Appreciated!